# precise definition for multiplicity

Tags: graph-theory

Multiplicity in graphs is the number of edges between two distinct vertices. But I'm not sure of the precise definition.
From what I've read, we need to consider directed edges for digraphs. for example, if there are two directed edges from a to b, then the multiplicity of (a,b) is 2. but what if there is another edge in the other direction i.e., (b,a), is the multiplicity of (a,b) still 2 or will it be 3?
How is the number of edges considered for undirected graphs? It would be helpful if you could specify using sets.

Comment: I know that vertices in directed graphs have indegrees and outdegrees; so perhaps they have inmultiplicities and outmultiplicities as well.

Comment: If you're asking about the precise definition, you're asking the wrong question. You should be asking instead either "what is the definition used in the proof of Theorem X?" or "what is the definition that fits the problem I am trying to solve?"

Answer (score 3):

For an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, the multiplicity of a vertex $v \in V$ is the number of edges incident to $v$, i.e.
$$d(v) := \#\{ e \in E \; | \; v \in e \}$$

For a directed graph $D = (W, A)$, we have the *in-degree*
$$d^-(w) := \#\{a \in A \; | \; \exists x \in V. a = (x, v)\}$$
which is the number of arrows going into $w$, and the *out-degree*
$$d^+(w) := \#\{a \in A \; | \; \exists x \in V. a = (v, x)\}$$
which is the number of arrows leading *out* of $w$.

These notions are standard.  Sometimes people also define the "degree" of a vertex in a directed graph to be
$$d(w) := d^+(w) + d^-(w),$$
the total number of arrows incident to $w$, but this is less common.

---

EDIT: The question is about multiplicities, not degrees, so we should consider graphs where $E$ or $A$ is a multiset and then restrict the above definitions to the edges or arrows between two given vertices.